# SymPy.solvers.solve() returns empty list

Tags: python, sympy

While using sympy.solve() to try and solve simple linear equations, the function just returns an empty list.

Here is my code:

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr as parse 

x = Symbol('x')
equation = input('Enter an equation: ')
equation = message.content.split()[1].replace('=',',')
solution = solve(parse(equation))
```

For `equation = 'x+3=8'`,  `print(solution)` just prints `[]`

Can anyone figure out why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you replacing `=` with `,`? This works: `solve(parse_expr('Eq(x+3,8)'))`

Comment: @Oscar Benjamin This codepiece is actually for a discord bot. The input will have an equal sign denoting the equation, not a comma. Try ```solve(parse_expr('Eq(x+3=8)'))``` and it raises an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the best practice here is, but using `Eq` here will work.
The code after a few changes-

```
from sympy import Symbol, Eq
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr as parse

x = Symbol('x')
equation_1 = input('Enter an equation: ')
equation_2 = equation_1.split('=')
solution = solve(Eq(*[parse(i) for i in equation_2]), x)
print(solution)
```

example output-

```
Enter an equation: x+1=x**2
[1/2 - sqrt(5)/2, 1/2 + sqrt(5)/2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to handle this parsing is to use the "battery" transformations:

```py
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, T
>>> parse_expr('x=1',transformations=T[1,9]) # auto-symbol and convert =
Eq(x, 1)
>>> solve(_)
[1]
```